# Change attribute coming from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Need in the list when you press "enter" on the item, switch to the corresponding video ie change the attribute the `<video>` tag `src=""`.

The path to the JSON Videos:

```
data.query.results.channel.item.guide.content.url
```

javascript:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    // Load Titles patch Json
    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.guide.content.map(function (item) {
        return item.title;

    });

    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));

    // Load Navigation Only Key
    a = $('.nav_holder li').keynav(function () {
        return window.keyNavigationDisabled;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/3/)

Comment: Do you just need to update the `src` attribute of your `<video>` tag? If so, you can just use `$("#myvideo").attr("src", "http://new-video-source.com/video");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/5/

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

        // Load Titles patch Json
        console.log(data.query.results.channel.item);
        var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
        return item.title;

        });
        var urls = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
            return item.origLink;

        });
        console.log(titles);
        $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
        $(".container-list-podcast ul li").each(function(key, value){
            var text = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<a href="' + urls[key] + '">' + text + '</a>');
        });
        $(".container-list-podcast ul li a").click(function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            alert(href);
            $("#myvideo").attr("src", href).get(0).play();
            return false;
        })
        // Load Navigation Only Key
            a=$('.nav_holder li').keynav(function() {
                return window.keyNavigationDisabled;
            });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Mangesh thanks for your reply, I put the video link in html example only, but when the page loads must always carry the latest video podcast. can you tell what would that be? Thank you.

Comment: Yes i know that. Check the jsfiddle link I have given. When page loads it carries the video link and when you click on the link it plays that video.